# Do multiple Jenkins masters on same host increase performance?

Tags: performance, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

Lets consider dozens/hundreds slaves on one machine. Is there a point in setting up multiple Jenkins masters on the same host to get better performance? Or maybe one big master does it better?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big master is always better @M.Stefanczuk

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: u can expect several problems related to file lock. Also you will be losing more ram because of two different Jenkins. I tried running 2 Jenkins in a machine it was really slow comparatively.